# where Jcomments data stored?

Tags: ios, joomla

I want to synchronise comments on my site (JComments) with comments in my app. If someone adds comment from site, it would be displayed in app and vice versa. I just need to know where the comments are stored, i'm sure i can handle it over there.

Any suggestions are pretty much appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have a URL for the component you've downloaded, so we can determine which one you're talking about? Failing that, an author would be a start (get that from extension manager, components, author column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for **jos_jcomments** table in your database.

http://www.joomlatune.com/jcomments-faq.html

Comment: Thank you! I found it exactly in there.